# Select works but analogical update doesn't want to

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm rather newbie in sql and i meet one problem.

I must update recently added column based on values in three columns. If the are the same as coresponding columns in other table then it must update this column based on value in other table.

This what i tried so far

```
update a 
set a.id = ( select top 1 b.id from OtherTable b 
     where b.k='Doz' and b.year = a.year and b.number = a.number)
from ThisTable a
```

and here is error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How there possibly can be more than one row if I used top 1?

My other try:

```
update a 
set a.id = b.id
from ThisTable a
inner join OtherTable b
on b.k = 'Doz' and a.year = b.year and a.number = b.number
```

Still problem remains.

If I do:

```
select b.id
from ThisTable a
inner join OtherTable b
on b.k = 'Doz' and a.year = b.year and a.number = b.number
```

I see all ids that should be updated. An when I add where clause with specified values for columns then I get only one record, not multiple.

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Have you tried running the sub query to see exactly what is returned? (From the first block of code)

Comment: It looks like you are not really updating one row. It looks like you are trying to update one row per year / number combination

Comment: Fred: As I wrote in the post I tried alternative select statement and results are as they should be. James: You may be right but even then it should return 1 row in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
update ThisTable 
set ThisTable.id = b.id
from ThisTable
     inner join othertable b
          on ThisTable.year = b.year
          and ThisTable.number = b.number
where b.k = 'doz'
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks for that. I'm after work right now but I'll check it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. It turned out that all queries were good. There were a problem with table trigger who fired every time I tried to update. I included execution plan and noticed additional queries. This is legacy database and I saw there is nothing in Programmability/Triggers folder, so I thought there aren't any triggers in database. 
I started to try all possible combination on query update with still the same result. 
Then I discovered table-level trigger. Sorry for confusion, newbie in ssms :)